# Problems Inserting Byte[] into SqlDataSource ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql

Maybe I'm just not googling the right parameters, but I just can't seem to figure this one out.
I've created a hashed password, which from my understanding, should be a byte array.
Then I need to insert that into the SqlDataSource and there's where my problem lies.

My database definition is as follows;

```
 
**Column**  || **Data Type**
----------------------------  
Name        || varchar(50)  
Username    || varchar(50)  
HashedPwd   || varbinary(50)  
Salt        || varbinary(50)  
UserType    || varchar(50)
```

My code is as follows;

```
HashAlgorithm hashing = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] passwordPlainText = (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()).GetBytes(txtPassword.ToString());
byte[] salt = (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()).GetBytes(RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().ToString());
// Combine salt and password before hashing.
byte[] saltAndPwd = new byte[passwordPlainText.Length + salt.Length];
Array.Copy(passwordPlainText, saltAndPwd, passwordPlainText.Length);
Array.Copy(salt, 0, saltAndPwd, passwordPlainText.Length, salt.Length);
byte[] hashedPwd = hashing.ComputeHash(saltAndPwd);

database.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
database.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO userlist (Name, Username, HashedPwd, Salt, Type) VALUES (@insName, @insUsername, @insHashedPass, @insSalt, @insType);";
database.InsertParameters.Add("insName", txtName.Text);
database.InsertParameters.Add("insUsername", txtUsername.Text);
database.InsertParameters.Add("insHashedPass", (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()).GetString(hashedPwd));
database.InsertParameters.Add("insSalt", (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()).GetString(salt));
database.InsertParameters.Add("insType", txtType.Text);
database.Insert();
```

The database stuff is what I've gleaned from research on the internet and seeing what options I'm given with the handy autocomplete feature in Visual Studio.
FYI I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.4, .Net Version 4.0.3
It seems there's some external libraries for SQL connections, but I would prefer to just use the inbuilt stuff the .Net provides.

At the moment, I recieve this error when running the insert algorithm;
**Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.**
I'm not sure how I would use the convert function.
The Add() method can take string, string like I'm currently doing or it can also take string, DbType, string.  I've tried `database.InsertParameters.Add("insSalt", DbType.Binary, salt);` but I can't even compile/build the website. I get; "Cannot convert from byte[] to String".
If I change it to `salt.ToString()` I get; "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Btye[]" on the Insert() line.

So yeah...really lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the **SqlDataSource**, it's for data-bound controls. What you need is **SqlConnection & SqlCommand**.
Here's what you do:

```
...your hashing code here...

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
{
    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userlist (Name, Username, HashedPwd, Salt, UserType) VALUES (@insName, @insUsername, @insHashedPass, @insSalt, @insType);";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("insName", txtName.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("insUsername", txtUsername.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("insHashedPass", hashedPwd));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("insSalt", salt));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("insType", txtType.Text));

    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also note, I've changed "Type" to "UserType" in your command text to match your DB table definition. You will need to replace the connection string to match yours, of course.

Comment: OK, that code works. Thanks for that.
Could you please clarify for me, why I don't use SqlDataSource though? Would I use SqlDataSource to access the GridView that displays the users and types from the database? That's kind of how it reads when I skim through this page; http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-bound-controls

Comment: You are welcome. Quoting the MSDN, SqlDataSource _"Represents an SQL database to data-bound controls."_ So yes, you can use it to pass data back and forth between it and the GridView, since the GridView _is_ a data-bound control. Here, on the other hand, you are just storing some data (not coming from any control) to a db table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. You need to check the class that is creating the hash to see what is the return type.

If the return type is string then you will not be able to assign to:

byte[] hashedPwd = hashing.ComputeHash(saltAndPwd);

Comment: Pretty sure VS would let me know if that was an issue. That said, I checked, ComputeHash(byte[]) returns byte[]